# Changed locale in CentOS 7 using localectl doesn't work

Tags: centos, centos7, localization

I want to change the localisation to `en_US.utf8` so that all log messages from applications were displayed in english. This works when I prefix the command with `LANG=en_US.utf ./my-command`, now every output of `./my-command` is english.

`localectl` seems the right tool to make it permanent, so I tried

```
[root@cnx65 ~]# localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8
```

But when now running `./my-command`, the output is still in german. According to `localectl`, we have `en_US.utf8` set:

```
[root@cnx65 ~]# localectl
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.utf8
       VC Keymap: de_alt_UTF-8
      X11 Layout: us
```

where `locale` and also the `$LANG` variable shows still german:

```
[root@cnx65 ~]# locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
[root@cnx65 ~]# echo $LANG
de_DE.UTF-8
```

I also verified that the locale exists with `localectl -a`:

```
[root@cnx65 ~]# locale -a | grep en_US.utf8
en_US.utf8
```

Why is this not working? It's not traceable for me. As you can see, all commands ran as root, so there couldn't be a permission issue.

I don't want to just set the `LANG` environment variable somwhere globally like in `/etc/profiles` since the server got provisioned by Ansible, so there's no interactive login shell.